# How to show an entirely new component on clicking a button in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I am having a login page, upon clicking the login button. It should load a complete new screen containing some stuff like dashboard.

The approaches given in internet is not matching to this requirement.

Any help is highly appreciated

Please find the code that I have written.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from '../app/admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent }
  ]}
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {enableTracing: false})
  ],
  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

On Click in Login component, the following method gets called

```
signIn() {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
  }
```

Auth guard Service is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just route to another component, what's the deal here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the approaches given on the Internet do match this requirement :)

It's called **routing** : what you need to do is basically :

- Create your login component
- Upon login, when you receive the response, redirect to another component.

First, your login component. Do an HTML form, and on validate, call your endpoint. Once the response received, you need to use this

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {} // from @angular/router
// Upon response do 
thismyService.login(username, pwd).subscribe(response => {
  this.router.navigate(['connected']);
});
```

Now, you have to define your routes. It would look like something like this :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'connected', component: ConnectedComponent }
  ]}
];
```

Made simple :

- You have a login component on default
- All of your other routes are in a group with guards (`AuthGuard`). If you don't know what guards are, [see this page](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). If you're not connected, then you can't access those routes.

Without further code, this is all the help I can get you. So I hope it helps !

**EDIT** sorry I did something wrong, your routes should be this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'connected', component: ConnectedComponent }
  ]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

You had two routes that were the same (empty path), now you have a login one and if the route isn't recognized, it will redirect to login

Comment: Please find my updated code. Let me know where I went wrong

Comment: Don't seem you did anything wrong, what is your error trace  ?

Comment: On clicking this, login page not going to anywhere, Expectation is, it should show the admin page

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, if possible, please share me the plunker code

Comment: I'm doing it out of memory, sorry ... But it should work now. Do you have an error ? is your guard called ?

Comment: Yes, AuthGuard#canActivate called

Comment: So it is called, but `admin works !` isn't showing  ?